# SQL Insert Error: ORA-00936

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having a really difficult time trying to figure out what exactly is wrong with this SQL Insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO mpcs.shop_inventory (
    SI_KEY,
    INV_TYPE,
    MTI_PART_NO,
    BUILD_NO,
    SERIAL_NO,
    HOME_LOCATION,
    HOME_LOCATION_SUB,
    DESCRIPTION,
    CATEGORY,
    QUANTITY,
    MIN_QTY,
    CONSUMABLE,
    CUST_PART_NO,
    UOM,
    WEIGHT,
    SCRAP_FLAG,
    NEXT_CAL,
    INTERVAL,
    SIZE_1,
    SIZE_2,
    SIZE_3
    )
VALUES (
    28990,
    'TEST',
    '01400010002',
    0,
    '0',
    'DEPT-850',
    'DEPT-850',
    'Test',
    '001',
    1,
    0,
    0,
    '',
    'BOTTLES',
    '3',
    0,
    to_date('27-June-2008', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),
    0,
    ,
    ,
    )
```

Comment: if you want to insert empty values either use NULL or empty string. `,,,` your commas at the end are not valid syntax

Comment: Im no Oracle expert but I am pretty sure you can't just add commas without something as a value (see the end of your statement). You need to include something.

Answer (score 2):

Like the comments suggest, try changing your ,,, to send NULL values instead

```
INSERT INTO mpcs.shop_inventory (
    SI_KEY,
    INV_TYPE,
    MTI_PART_NO,
    BUILD_NO,
    SERIAL_NO,
    HOME_LOCATION,
    HOME_LOCATION_SUB,
    DESCRIPTION,
    CATEGORY,
    QUANTITY,
    MIN_QTY,
    CONSUMABLE,
    CUST_PART_NO,
    UOM,
    WEIGHT,
    SCRAP_FLAG,
    NEXT_CAL,
    INTERVAL,
    SIZE_1,
    SIZE_2,
    SIZE_3
    )
VALUES (
    28990,
    'TEST',
    '01400010002',
    0,
    '0',
    'DEPT-850',
    'DEPT-850',
    'Test',
    '001',
    1,
    0,
    0,
    '',
    'BOTTLES',
    '3',
    0,
    to_date('27-June-2008', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
    )
```

Comment: No you want 3 nulls at the end or the # of columns' doesnt match values.  21 columns, 20 values.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Just edited

Answer (score 0):

```
Can use directly the columns you want to insert only in insert statement:

    INSERT INTO mpcs.shop_inventory (
        SI_KEY,
        INV_TYPE,
        MTI_PART_NO,
        BUILD_NO,
        SERIAL_NO,
        HOME_LOCATION,
        HOME_LOCATION_SUB,
        DESCRIPTION,
        CATEGORY,
        QUANTITY,
        MIN_QTY,
        CONSUMABLE,
        CUST_PART_NO,
        UOM,
        WEIGHT,
        SCRAP_FLAG,
        NEXT_CAL,
        INTERVAL
        )
    VALUES (
        28990,
        'TEST',
        '01400010002',
        0,
        '0',
        'DEPT-850',
        'DEPT-850',
        'Test',
        '001',
        1,
        0,
        0,
        '',
        'BOTTLES',
        '3',
        0,
        to_date('27-June-2008', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),
        0
        );

Just keep it simple.
```